# Skipping lines of code depending on available function(s)/toolboxes

Tags: matlab, debugging, parallel-processing, spmd

**Context**

At work I built a GUI to perform image registration on several microscopy images. On the computer I'm using (i.e. at work) the Parallel Processing Toolbox is installed, so I can take advantage of [spmd](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/spmd.html) blocks to distribute the work on the computer's cores.

First I create a [codistributed](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/codistributed.codistributed.html?searchHighlight=codistributed) array to split my array into smaller chunks:

```
spmd

    DistributedCell = codistributed.cell(NumberFrames)
   ...
end
```

All is well until I run the code on my own laptop, on which the Parallel Processing Toolbox is not installed. Obviously I can't use `spmd` blocks and codistributed arrays so I wrote non-parallelized code to register the images, which works equally well but takes longer to execute.

**The problem**

The problem I'm having is that the code in `spmd` blocks needs to be commented when I'm using my home laptop, otherwise Matlab complains that:

```
MATLAB cannot determine whether "codistributed"
refers to a function or variable.
```

So even if I check whether I have the PP toolbox installed (or not) and use a condition to execute different commands depending on whether it is or not as follows:

```
%// Check for parallel toolbox installed
if ~isempty(ver('parallel'))

  NON-PARALLEL code...

else

  PARALLEL code...

   spmd 
      PROBLEM HERE                            
      DistributedCell = codistributed.cell(NumberFrames)
      ...
   end
end
```

Matlab won't evaluate the condition of the `if` statement and will throw the error I mentioned above. This is quite cumbersome since every time I use the code on my laptop I need to comment all the lines generating the error (there are many of them) and vice versa when I'm at work.

**Question**

Is it possible to avoid commenting the code manually and make Matlab don't bother about codistributed arrays when it is running on a computer on which the PP toolbox is not installed?

Maybe I missed something obvious in the debugging world but I can't get around it.

I'm running on Mac if that can be useful (R2015a at work and R2013a at home).

**EDIT**

To clarify the situation:

The error pops up before any line of code is executed at all. I guess Matlab parses the whole code before executing any of it, so the only way I can avoid it is to comment it. That does not happen with other functions (in this case the classic `undefined function [...]` appears) but I can avoid it with the `if/else` statement. It really is the `codistributed` term that Matlab does not like.

Comment: Did you check simply `if exist('codistributed')`?

Comment: First which comes to mind is `try PARALLEL code  catch NON-PARALLEL code...`. Second: why not put `spmd ...  end` in an external script? But what I don't understand, how can your code reach the problematic line if you don't have the toolbox installed? Shouldn't that be avoided by the if-condition?

Comment: And apart from that `ver('parallel')` does not make sense in Matlab2015a? You could try `x = ver; any(ismember({x.Name},'Parallel Computing Toolbox'))` instead.

Comment: Does it throw this error only when using `spmd`, or also when you use just any function from a non-installed toolbox?

Comment: thanks for your comments I'll edit the question with info I forgot to provide.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `~isempty(ver('distcomp'))`?

Comment: Better yet: `if exist('codistributed','class') == 8`? A `try`/`catch` could also be used to catch the specific error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use

```
ver('distcomp')
```

for your `if` condition, not `ver('parallel')`. Very confusing, I know.

How can you find out what name you need for `ver`? The best way I know is if you look in the folder `matlabroot\toolbox` (where `matlabroot` is your installation folder), you'll see a number of folders, mostly one per toolbox. The name you need for `ver` is typically  the same as the name of the toolbox folder - in this case, it's `distcomp`.

Early versions of Parallel Computing Toolbox were named Distributed Computing Toolbox, hence the folder name, which has not been updated.

Edit:

You may also, or instead, like to test whether you have a *license* for PCT, rather than testing whether it's *installed*, which is what `ver` tests for.

You can do this with `license('test', 'Distrib_Computing_Toolbox')`.

How do you know it's `Distrib_Computing_Toolbox` that you need? This time, you need to look in your license file (probably `something.lic` in the folder `matlabroot\licenses`, and scroll through the products until you find the name of the relevant toolbox. The product names in the license bear no relationship to the product folders used by `ver`.

These confusing and differing product names drive me nuts, but there you go.

Comment: thanks for the clarifications Sam. I should check my sources more thoroughly haha.

Answer (score 0):

I would go this way:

```
>> foo = ver;

>> foo.Name
ans =
MATLAB
ans =
Signal Processing Toolbox
```

So if you can branch on whether you  find the string "Parallel" in any `foo(j).Name`